# Setting layers from GeoJSON property

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers, fields-attributes, feature-filter

I have a .js  file with 19000 entries from where I want to create layers from a feature.properties.Issue. I have tried diferent approaches I have found in here but for some reason the layers are not displayed. I am trying to use the Leaflet filter to do so. How can I do this?

I´m using the code above:

The .js file example is as follow:

```
var data = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "maclora": "0004A30B00FB82F0",
        "serial_num": 202103000002777,
        "model": "OCTANS 40",
        "latitude": 38.569244417,
        "longitude": -8.88123655,
        "JR_RSSI": "-115,54",
        "JR_SNR": "-0,78",
        "Issue": "Sem JA"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -8.88123655,
          38.569244417
        ]
      }
    },

    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "maclora": "0004A30B00FBA297",
        "serial_num": 202103000002779,
        "model": "OCTANS 40",
        "latitude": 38.569850281,
        "longitude": -8.881527801,
        "JR_RSSI": "-116,72",
        "JR_SNR": "-4,95",
        "Issue": "Sem JR"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -8.881527801,
          38.569850281
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "maclora": "0004A30B00EDA56B",
        "serial_num": 202104000047982,
        "model": "SCULPTOR 140",
        "latitude": 38.5561081661,
        "longitude": -8.89268654685,
        "JR_RSSI": "-113,82",
        "JR_SNR": "-1,64",
        "Issue": "Sem JR"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -8.89268654685,
          38.5561081661
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "maclora": "0004A30B00ED5DA4",
        "serial_num": 202104000047986,
        "model": "SCULPTOR 140",
        "latitude": 38.5557449488,
        "longitude": -8.89278445244,
        "JR_RSSI": "-121,87",
        "JR_SNR": "-9,41",
        "Issue": "Sem Uplinks"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -8.89278445244,
          38.5557449488
        ]
      }
    },
  ]
};
```

The html file as the following code:

```
function setPopup(feature,layer) {
  var popupContent = '<b><span style="color:#eb991e;">MacloRa:</span> ' +
      feature.properties.maclora +
      '<br><span style="color:#eb991e;">Serial Number: </span> ' +
      '<small>' +
      feature.properties.serial_num +
      '<br><span style="color:#eb991e;">Issue: </span> ' +
      feature.properties.Issue +
      '<br><span style="color:#eb991e;">Last UL: </span> ' +
      +feature.properties.last_ul +
      '<br><span style="color:#eb991e;">Last JR: </span> ' +
      feature.properties.last_jr +
      '<br><span style="color:#eb991e;">Last JA </span> ' +
      feature.properties.last_ja;
  
  layer.on('mouseover',function(ev) {
      ev.target.openPopup();
  });
  layer.on('mouseout',function(ev) {
      ev.target.closePopup();
  });
  layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
}

function getColor(stype) {
  switch (stype) {
    case 'Sem JA':
      return  'blue';
    case 'Ok':
      return 'green';
    case 'Sem JR':
      return 'orange';
    case 'Sem Uplinks':
      return 'red';
    default:
      return 'white';
  }
}

var ja = L.geoJson(data, {
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return (feature.properties.Issue === "Sem JA");
  },
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 5, 
        fillOpacity: 1, 
        color: 'black', 
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Issue), 
        weight: 1,});
    },
    onEachFeature: setPopup,
});

var jr = L.geoJson(data, {
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return (feature.properties.Issue === "Sem JR");
  },
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 5, 
        fillOpacity: 1, 
        color: 'black', 
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Issue), 
        weight: 1,});
    },
    onEachFeature: setPopup,
});

var ul = L.geoJson(data, {
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return (feature.properties.Issue === "Sem Uplinks");
  },
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 5, 
        fillOpacity: 1, 
        color: 'black', 
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Issue), 
        weight: 1,});
    },
    onEachFeature: setPopup,
});

var ok = L.geoJson(data, {
  
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return (feature.properties.Issue === "OK");
  }, 
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 5, 
        fillOpacity: 1, 
        color: 'black', 
        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Issue), 
        weight: 1,});
    },
    onEachFeature: setPopup,
});

var addOverlay = {
  "OK": ok,
  "Sem Uplinks": ul,
  "Sem JR": jr,
  "Sem JA": ja,
}

layerControl.addOverlay(baseLayers, addOverlay).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Hi @TomazicM  thanks for the insight. You might be right. I have deleted unnecessary text and left what´s important.

Comment: Getting any errors in the browser debugger console?

Comment: getColor and setPopup are not specified in your code. It is not a runnable minimal example. Please try to provide a runnable minimal example, e.g. using jsfiddle. Often you stumble over the error yourself when you try to create a minimal example.

Comment: Hi TomazicM I wasn´t getting any errors and after checking @til_b example I came to the conclusion I was not setting the var L.control.layers porperly. Another error I have found was instead of defining the feature.properties.Issue === "Ok" I was defining it as OK (with both capital letters), Dumb me :)   Thanks for the help.

Comment: I always get confused when I use a L.control.layers and need to see example code to get it to work ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to build a JSFiddle minimal example that shows an error I came to a working solution and could not find an error.

See jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/cgdaLjhv/1/ .

The relevant code is

```
var data = { /* as in question*/ };

var map = L.map("map").setView([38.5,-8.8], 9);

var osmBase = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'
});

var getColor = function(i) {
  var c = "blue"
  if (i=="Sem JA") {
    c = "red";
  }
  return c;
}

var setPopup = function(feature,layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('<p>'+feature.properties.serial_num+': '+feature.properties.Issue+'</p>');
}

var baseLayers = {
    "OSM": osmBase
}

var lc = L.control.layers(baseLayers)

lc.addTo(map);

var ja = L.geoJson(data, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      return (feature.properties.Issue === "Sem JA");
    },
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng) {
        return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 5, 
            fillOpacity: 1, 
            color: 'black', 
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Issue), 
            weight: 1,})
    },
    onEachFeature: setPopup
  } // end json layer options
); // end json layer ja

var jr = L.geoJson(data, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
      return (feature.properties.Issue === "Sem JR");
    },
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng) {
      return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {radius: 5, 
          fillOpacity: 1, 
          color: 'black', 
          fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.Issue), 
          weight: 1,})
    },
    onEachFeature: setPopup
  } // end json layer options
); // end json layer jr

lc.addOverlay(ja, "JA");
lc.addOverlay(jr, "JR");
```

What I did was to build an example from scratch, trying one thing at a time. First adding the JSON without any options. Then specifying a single option (the markers). Then the filters. After each step i check if everything displays as I expect; that way you can  really narrow down where you get your errors.

Comment: Hi @til_b, yes exactly that was my approach and first I did put the code that worked (same steps as you). But after a while I couldn´t get it to work. I guess I need some distance from the problem. I´ll check your example, but thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the help, mate really helped a lot. I also have found that insted of defining feature.properties.Issue === "Ok" I was writing OK (both capital letters :)